# Op-amp amplifier with swapping pins

Tags: operational-amplifier

While learning the amplifiers with Op-Amps, I saw that for the inverting amplifier the source is connected to the inverting terminals of the op-amp and for the non-inverting amplifier, source is connected to the non-inverting terminals. My question is if I swap the pins for inverting amplifiers (or in non-inverting amplifiers) as shown in the picture below, will it still work as a non-inverting amplifier?

My understanding is if we are talking about ideal op-amps, it would not be a problem. I was wondering about real op-amps. In other words, what is the difference between the non-inverting terminal and the inverting terminal?

[image]

Thank you.
Khalid

Comment: You have your diagrams labels swapped - your "new amplifier" is actually the standard "inverting amplifier" configuration. And if your understanding of ideal opamps leads you to believe that just swapping the input pins around would work - then I'm sorry to have to tell you that you don't really understand opamps at all. The standard opamp configurations only work because they provide *negative feedback*. Do you have any negative feedback if you're feeding back into the non-inverting (+) input?

Comment: Hi Brhans,Thank you for your comment. But then my question is, what will happen for this new configuration? (I have edited the picture). Also I said that for ideal op-amps it would work because after applying KCL I always get the same answer.

Comment: Ok - you've fixed the labels. You should post some of your calculations where you get what looks like the same answer so we can see what you've done.

Comment: Take a look to this ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/573990/how-to-explain-the-strange-results-from-this-circuit-op-amp-differential-ampl

Answer (score 1):

> *My question is if I swap the pins for inverting amplifiers (or in
> non-inverting amplifiers) as shown in the picture below, will it still
> work as a non-inverting amplifier?*

No, it will turn into a voltage comparator with hysteresis. Google is your friend here.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @KhalidIbneMasood please [take the two minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand more about this site and learn how to complete a question and answer session.